# Continuous function of a projection operator is itself?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $\{\psi_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of unit elements of a given Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. These are not necessarily orthogonal. For each of these vectors, define the projection operator $P_{n}$ which sends $\mathscr{H} \ni \varphi \mapsto \langle \psi_{n},\varphi\rangle \psi_{n}$. Define a new operator:
$$T = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\lambda_{n}P_{n}$$
with $\lambda_{n} \ge 0$ and $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\lambda_{n} = 1$. I am trying to prove the following: for every continuous function $f$ on $\sigma(T)$
$$f(T) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}f(\lambda_{n})P_{n}$$

My attempt is the following: first, note that $T$ is linear, bounded and self-adjoint. By the spectral theorem, since $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\lambda_{n}P_{n} \to T$ then:
$$f(T) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}f(\lambda_{n}P_{n}) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}f(\lambda_{n})f(P_{n})$$

The result then would follow if $f(P_{n}) = P_{n}$. But I can't give a reasonable justification why this is true. Any help?

Comment: If the $\psi_n$ are not orthogonal, then this fails to fold, even in the finite dimensional case. Try thinking about two-dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Comment: If $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are not orthogonal then $(P_1+P_2)^2\neq P_1+P_2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this statement does not hold. As a counterexample, consider the following vectors and values over $\Bbb C^2$:
$$
\psi_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad \psi_2 = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1\\1}, \quad \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 1.
$$
If you like, you can extend this to an infinite sequence by selecting $\psi_n$ arbitrarily and taking $\lambda_n = 0$ for $n \geq 3$. If we take $f:x \to x^2$, then we have
$$
f(\lambda_1 P_1 + \lambda_2 P_2) = \pmatrix{3/2 & 1/2\\1/2 & 1/2}^2 = \frac 12 \pmatrix{5 & 2\\2 & 1},\\
f(\lambda_1)P_1 + f(\lambda_2) P_2 = \lambda_1 P_1 + \lambda_2 P_2 = \frac 12 \pmatrix{3 & 1\\1& 1} .
$$

Comment: Thanks! So, the result only holds if the vectors $\{\psi_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are orthogonal?

Comment: It just ocurred to me that $f(P_{n}) = P_{n}$ because this holds for polynomials, which is dense in the space of continuous functions right?

Comment: @Idontgetit It's not true for $f:x \mapsto 2x$. The fact that $f(P_n) = P_n$ in this case holds because $\sigma(P_n) = \{0,1\}$